Is there an L-system for coral sea fans?
I've been looking at several kinds of sea fan such as:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorgonia_ventalina
It occurred to me that this could likely be modelled with an L-system, but I couldn't see anyone who had done this.  There would have to be some sort of restrictions on the branches so that they intersect to make a mesh.  Does anyone know if this has been done? I can see it probably has some similarities to Parrish & Muller's application of L-systems to cities.
